# Square brackets next to an object - What's the notation called?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

**What's the name for the square brackets syntax in this snippet?**

And - just to clarify - is it accessing the default field inside 'label' and changing that?

I seem to think it is called 'binding' - but I've got literally no idea where I got that idea from

```
def change_text():
    label["text"] = entry.get()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on the context, it can be referred to as:

- item getting/setting (e.g. dicts)
- `__getitem__` /  `__setitem__` / get-key / set-key (e.g. dicts)
- indexing (e.g. my_list[3])
- slicing (e.g. my_list[1:3])
- subscripting (thanks, @AnotherTest)

By "context" I mean: the type of the object (`label`), the type of the object inside the brackets (`"text"`), whether the square brackets are in the right-hand-side or left (get or set)...

Comment: I've heard "subscripting" as well.

Answer (score 6):

In the [python grammar](http://docs.python.org/3.1/reference/grammar.html) it can be summarized as "subscripting".

The [python doc](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-subscription) calls it "subscription".

Comment: No it isn't called a "subscription", the word doesn't appear on the page. A "subscription" is a state of being subscribed to something. The act of using a subscript is "subscripting".

Comment: @SteveJessop Thank you. I have edited my answer. The grammar talks about "subscripts" and "subscriptlists". A "subscriptlist" between square brackets is a "trailer" as well as a function call or a member access.

Comment: Right, my point is just that the word "subscription" happens to have nothing to do with "subscripts", although it probably should.

Comment: @SteveJessop Please elaborate. A "subscript" (<sub-scribo = I write beneath) is something written below something else. A "subscription" is the act of writing something below something else. Sure, subscription has special meanings in different contexts (e.g. news letter subscription, etc, but after all this also refers to writing your name under the list of recipients), but I don't see why "subscription" shouldn't be the act of using "subscripts".

Comment: @SteveJessop http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-subscription . Cf. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subscription "the ACT of signing one's name"

Comment: Sure, "subscribe" and "subscript" have the same Latin origin but that doesn't make them interchangeable. Since the descriptive documentation (if not the grammar spec) calls it "a subscription" instead of "a subscript", then fair enough, you're correct that's a Python jargon term. It's still incorrect English, but that doesn't matter for jargon :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop I don't know if you have visited the link above, but Merriam-Webster clearly states that "subscription" is the act (sic!) of signing. Which according to your definition is not true. Now I am not sure, whom I should trust concerning "incorrect Engligh".

Comment: I don't know what makes you argue that a signature on a document is the same thing as what's in square brackets in Python. It is not. If it said in M-W that a "subscription" is "a small letter or number written at/below the line, used in mathematics to indicate an index" then of course that would be relevant. It doesn't. Both are "written underneath" (because the square brackets replace the mathematical convention of writing indexes below the line), nevertheless in English the word for what's written below the line is different from the word for what's written at the end of a document.